# UC Davis (1.3.6.1.4.1.2021) MIBS not working with SNMPv3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snmp, snmpd, snmpv3

I made a SNMPv3 setup in order to test how it can be integrated with some third party scripts.

I need to use some of the MIBS from 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021 in order to do this but couldn't manage to successfully do this part.
Currently only SNMPv1 and SNMPv2 return the expected results with snmpwalk while I'm using the rocommunity.

Already lost more than 1 day looking into the logs, running packet and process dumps in order to figure what was the problem. 
In the end figured out that everything seems to be normal for SNMPv1 and SNMPv2.
The rocommunity seems to solve the problem for v1 and v2, but for v3 this part isn't enough.

If someone else has experienced this problem or has an idea please share.

Here are some details about my setup.

### > cat /etc/*release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

### > cat /etc/snmp/snmp.conf

```
# As the snmp packages come without MIB files due to license reasons, loading
# of MIBs is disabled by default. If you added the MIBs you can reenable
# loading them by commenting out the following line.
mibs +ALL
```

### > cat /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

```
syslocation  MyLocation
syscontact  admins@mylocation.lan
sysservices 72

createUser usr-automation MD5 AUNIKTOKENISHERE01 DES usr-automation-pass
createUser usr-automation5 MD5 AUNIKTOKENISHERE05 DES usr-automation5-pass
createUser usr-automation7 MD5 AUNIKTOKENISHERE07 DES usr-automation7-pass

rwuser usr-automation priv 1.3.6.1.2.1
rouser usr-automation5 priv 1.3.6.1.2.1
rouser usr-automation7 priv 1.3.6.1.2.1

rocommunity AUNIKTOKENISHERE00
```

### > dpkg --list | grep snmp

```
ii  libsnmp-base                     5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.1             all          SNMP configuration script, MIBs and documentation
ii  libsnmp30:amd64                  5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.1             amd64        SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library
ii  snmp                             5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.1             amd64        SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) applications
ii  snmp-mibs-downloader             1.1                                 all          Install and manage Management Information Base (MIB) files
ii  snmpd                            5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.1             amd64        SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) agents
```

The results from the snmpwalk commands are as follows:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c AUNIKTOKENISHERE00 localhost 1.3.6 | grep 2021 
# result is as expected

snmpwalk -v 2c -c AUNIKTOKENISHERE00 localhost 1.3.6 | grep 2021 
# result is as expected

snmpwalk -v 3 -u usr-automation7 -l authPriv -a MD5 -A AUNIKTOKENISHERE07 -x DES -X usr-automation7-pass | grep 2021 
# returns only some basic informations which isn't enough (ex: iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 ), but the 2021 MIBS are missing
```